# MacTeX 2019, asymptote stopped working using the `-render` option

Tags: asymptote

Yesterday I installed TeXLive 2019 on my Mac using MacTeX 2019. I am working quite a lot with `asymptote`, so I was surprised, that `asy` seemed to have stopped working. No error message, but also no resulting `png` (I like `png`s).

Today I found out that for any `.asy` the command `asy -f png myFile.asy` perfectly produces a png in a quite bad resolution, as does `asy -f png -render 0 myFile.asy` (well, `0` is the default). But any value larger than 0 results in no png being created.

My preferred setting would be 4 or even 5. Can somebody confirm, that for now it stopped working? What did change in asymptote (or the converter used to get from `.eps` to `.png`) that made it stop working and how can I get that back?

*Edit*: To also provide an example, let's just draw two arrows

```
import settings;
import three;
size(7cm);
DefaultHead.size=new real(pen p=currentpen) {return 1.8mm;};
currentprojection=perspective( camera = (0.0, 0.0, 4.0), up=Y, target = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) );

draw( (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)--(0.7071, 0.7071, 0.0), rgb(0.565, 0.128,0.550), Arrow3);
draw( (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)--(1.6, 0.7071, 0.0), rgb(0.128,0.565,0.550), Arrow3);
```

Then

- `asy example.asy` produces a nice `eps`
- `asy -f png example.asy` produces a quite low res png (since 2019 with transparent background)
- `asy -f png -render 1 example.asy` does not give an error, but neither produces a file, the same for setting render to 2,3,4 or 5.
- as marmot suggested I also tried putting `settings.render=4;` into the file, which has the same effect as the last try with `-render` (so at least its consistently broken).

Comment: Could you perhaps add an explicit example?

Comment: I reproduce the effect also when I add `settings.render=4;` to the asy file.

Comment: I extended my Question and added an example and the variations I tried as well as your suggestion.

Comment: As a workaround until this bug is fixed you could try to stop liking `png`s, or to convert the `eps`s to high resolution bitmaps with another tool.

Comment: Which tool could you recommend for Mac OS here? I've never worked with eps.

Comment: Imagemagick `convert`, available for all platforms, which has tons of options (also for transparency etc.).

Comment: It is a OpenGL problem (from Asymptote bin or drivers pbs). It seems that OpenGL will be deprecated under Apple, it should work during a few years. Could you verify that OpenGL is ok ? If it is ok, could verify the output of `asy -vv -render 4 example.asy` (or `-vvv`). What happens with `asy -V example.asy` (the interactive OpenGL renderer) ?

Comment: `-vv` and `-vvv` don't show any errors they include and load (quite) a few things and finish with adjusting camera and target; However `-V` does the same as `-render 4`: exactly nothing. Waiting a few weeks even, would be quite sad, since I depend on that working for my research.

Comment: Try to compile Asymptote or downgrade to Texlive 2018. If you have urgent files to compile send me a mail (Europe timezone)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I'll try to downgrade, then.

Comment: So for now, one can just use the TeX Live Utility delivered with MacTeX and switch back to 2018, then `asy` works again.

Comment: Any news on this issue? I am now switching back and forth, to 2018 for asy to 2019 for the newest fontawesome – and it would be nice not to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error posten in the original question was a bug with MacTeX (TexLive) 2019. With MacTeX 2020, this is fixed. To get the rendering option back and work correctly, update to MacTeX 2020; tested with Mac OS Catalina.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/189854)

Comment: hm, well basically the question posted above by myself is fixed by updating to MacTeX 2020, what more should be given here? I am the original author, and this is the answer that solves the question.

Comment: Excuse me very much. :-( I'm sorry I have not seen that the author was yourself. +1

Comment: Nevermind :) I took your comment to extend the answer at least.